# How to animate a <div> from 0 to 70% incrementally with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, animation, increment

I am wanting to make a positioned `<div>` element that animates from 0 to 70% in 2px increments.

I'm wanting to do this for a specific computer-prompt like effect on load.

Can this be a thing, and would it be compatible with at least Firefox and Chrome?

Comment: Not moving the div, but incrementally growing the height property.

Comment: I'll try that, thanks. I was messing around with canvas before I realised there should be a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to animate with JavaScript. One library that makes it particularly easy to do so is jQuery using the `animate()` function. Since you have not posted example code, an example of how to use the `animate()` function is all I'm able to post with:

HTML:

```
<div id="clickme">
  Click here
</div>
<img id="book" src="book.png" alt="" width="100" height="123"
  style="position: relative; left: 10px;">
```

JavaScript:

```
// This will handle your onLoad requirement
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $( "#clickme" ).click(function() {
      $( "#book" ).animate({
        opacity: 0.25,
        left: "+=50",
        height: "toggle"
      }, 5000, function() {
        // Animation complete.
      });
    });
});
```